# Django - Displaying a user list takes over 14 seconds, how to speed it up?

Tags: django, django-views

I have a view that will display members based on the letter someone select(ex: clicking L on the webpage will display all the members whose firstname start with L, ordered by lastname)

The problem is that it can take over 14 seconds to display the page(like"M", around 180 members to list, 17 seconds or so to do so.) .  The SQL query doesn't seems the problem since Debug Toolbar reports that it takes less than a second for the query.

Here is the view:

```
def show_all_members(request, letter):
    members = MyUsers.objects.filter(firstname__istartswith=letter).order_by('lastname')
    alphabet = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
    request.session['url'] = request.get_full_path()
    context_dict = {'all_members': members, 'alphabet': alphabet}
    return render(request, "users/show_all_members.html", context_dict)
```

Programming is a hobby so I'm a bit lost on what is happening here and how to optimize it.  Any help and pointer is appreciated.

Using Django 2.1.1

Edit:  Here is the template.  It shows if the member has bought punchcards or access passes and also a link to his profile.

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load i18n %}
{% block title %}Members{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container">
  <div class="page-header" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
    <h2>Tribe members list</h2>

    {% for l in alphabet %}
      <a href="{% url 'users:show_all_members' l %}" class="btn btn-success"> 
        {{ l }}

      </a>
    {% endfor %}
   
  </div>
  <br>

  {% for user in all_members %}


    <div class="row"> 
    <p>
      <div class="col-md-2">
          <a href="{% url 'users:member_info' user.id %}" >
            <h7>{{ user.fullname  }}</h7>
          </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1">
          <a class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" href="{% url 'users:edit_profile_full' user.id %}"> Edit Profile</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
          <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" href="{% url 'classes:buy_pass' user.id  %}"> Current PC/SP</a>
          {%if user.punchcardbyuser_set.all %}
            {%for pc in user.punchcardbyuser_set.all %}
            <span class="badge badge-primary" >{{ pc.cardclasstype.name }}:{{ pc.classes }}</span>
            {%endfor%}           
          {% endif %}

          {%if user.allaccesspassbyuser_set.all %}
          {%for aap in user.allaccesspassbyuser_set.all %}
          <span class="badge badge-danger">AAP:{{ aap.classes }}</span>
          {%endfor%}           
        {% endif %}
        
        {%if user.seasonpass_set.all %}
        /
          {%for sp in user.seasonpass_set.all %}
            <span class="badge badge-primary">{{ sp.label }}</span>
          {%endfor%}
        {% endif %}
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
          <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" href="{% url 'classes:buy_pass' user.id  %}"> Buy passes</a>

     
           <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="{% url 'users:detail' user.username %}">Class attended: {{user.classes_set.all|length}}</a>

      </div>
    </p>
    </div>

  {% endfor %}
  
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Do you know where the performance hit happens? Did you profile what part takes long? Perhaps it is the rendering. In that case it might be better to share the template.

Comment: What are you displaying for each user? Does it involve further database queries?

Comment: How many users are there?

Comment: This looks like the *n+1* problem. You need to prefetch related objects you want to render: https://hackernoon.com/all-you-need-to-know-about-prefetching-in-django-f9068ebe1e60

Comment: I didn't use any profiler, no.  After doing a quck search it seems many are abandoned.  Do you recommend one?

Comment: 147 users displayed for M

Comment: As suggested by Willem, I'm reading about N+1, I think it is related, yes.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Willem Van Onsem tips, I read on Django N+1 and it was indeed the problem.  I had 747 queries in total...(!) (The page does display alot of informations from different M2M relations.)  By reading on "prefetch_related" and some fiddling, it is now down to 7 and the page now loads in 1.2 seconds max.  I'm sure I could get it lower by learning more about optimizing queries.

```
members = MyUsers.objects.filter(firstname__istartswith=letter).order_by('lastname').prefetch_related("punchcardbyuser_set").prefetch_related("classes_set").\
                                prefetch_related("allaccesspassbyuser_set").prefetch_related("seasonpass_set")
```

Thanks!